# Planning Calendar - Missing Property

Tags: sapui5

When I use the Chrome Dev Tools and the UI5 Inspector to look at the properties of the PlanningCalendar control, I find a property named "Info" (sap.m._PlanningCalendarRowHeader).

If I change this property a small text is displayed in the right area of the header column. Also an "InfoState" property can be set. Now I would like to set this in the XML view or from the coding.
No matter what I try, I can't get it working. I also can't really find anything in the OPENUI5 documentation.

Maybe one of you has a similar issue and can give me a hint how to set these properties directly in the XML View.

I have tried with the following browsers: MS Edge, Chrome and Safari in their respective current versions. I used the OPENUI5 framework in version 1.108.16.

On the page you can find an example where you can try it out. Important are only the Dev Tools and the UI5 Inspector.

https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.108.16/#/entity/sap.m.PlanningCalendar/sample/sap.m.sample.PlanningCalendar